# Smarty in javascript in prestashop template

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop, smarty

I am trying to create data layer with id's of products in prestashop cart page (.tpl file).

Here's smarty code that displays products id's added to cart

```
{foreach $products as $product}
      {$product.id_product}
    {/foreach}
```

It displays it in this way: 123 284 495 392

I would like to make id's appear in script this way:

```
{literal}
<script>
  gtag('event', 'page_view', {'send_to': 'AW-‎XXXXXXXX',
   'ecomm_prodid': '123,284,495,392',
   'ecomm_pagetype': 'cart',
   'ecomm_totalvalue': '{/literal}{displayPrice price=$total_products_wt}{literal}'
  });
</script>
 {/literal}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `not last item` conditional, within your foreach loop like this :

```
{literal}
<script>
gtag('event', 'page_view', {'send_to': 'AW-‎XXXXXXXX',
'ecomm_prodid': [{/literal}{foreach from=$products item=product name=prodid}'{$product.id_product}'{if $smarty.foreach.prodid.last}{else},{/if}{/foreach}{literal}]‌​,
'ecomm_pagetype': 'cart',
'ecomm_totalvalue': '{/literal}{displayPrice price=$total_products_wt}{literal}'
});
</script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: It shows like this: 0\, 7\, 1\, 1\, P\, 0\, <\, C\, C\, 7\, 9\, 0\, 0\, 0\, 0\, 1\, \, 1\, \, 0\, -\, 0\, 0\, 0\, 2\, 0\, 2\, 2\, 1\, p\, p\, 0\, 2\, 1\, \, \, \, \, \, P\, \, \, \, 1\, 2\, 7\, P\, a\, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, P\, \, -\, \, 
with information from Google Tag Assistant, that "Multiple product IDs need to be stored in an array."

Comment: Updated my code, changed `$product` to `$products`. What's the output now?

Comment: What's the content of each `$product`?

Comment: I made it this way: 'ecomm_prodid': [{/literal}{foreach from=$products item=product name=prodid}'{$product.id_product}'{if $smarty.foreach.prodid.last}{else},{/if}{/foreach}{literal}],
Thanks anyway, edit your code, you were helpful.